# Probability for the lottery extraction to be rigged

Tags: probability, fraud-detection

This draw of lottery, based on 7/39 numbers stirred a lot of debates, and an obvious anger of general public here in Serbia. I ran all kinds of scenarios in my head about what really happened here (or nothing special at all, which is possible too). So, the lottery is 7 out of 39 numbers. If you have a ticket with all 7 numbers circled, you win the jackpot. With some simple combinatorics, the probability for a jackpot for you is about 1/10,000,000. The extraction works in the manner that the numbered balls (numbered from 1-39) are going out of the dome and into the transparent glass tube, so us, the spectators, can clearly see which numbers are extracted at any moment. The numbers were beginning to go out of the glass dome, and the numbers were:

4, 33, 12

All regular, everything is fine until now. Then, 27 came out, but displayed on the screen (the digitally displayed figures numbers in the bottom part of the screen) were both 21 and 27 (even though only 27 got out). An obvious mistake, you would think. Happens very very rarely, but hey, it can happen. I never saw it before in my life on a lottery extraction, nor will I (and that is most probable) ever see it again during my life. The balls that went out of the glass dome are now:

4, 33, 12, 27

But, as I said, the screen shows:

4, 33, 12, 21, 27

After this happened, bear in mind, AFTER this happened, the next ball that got out of the dome is 21 (which kind of indicates that the computer is somehow psychic or something....). The lottery girl (a lovely girl speaking out the numbers) was confused and was calling everyone around the room to fix the error on the screen, and through some commotion, the studio fixes the error (after a disaster displaying on the screen, including a row of seven 27s, etc......a complete mess).

My question is what is the probability for a fraud (for the drawing machine to be rigged) here, and what is the probability that this was just a random one time error with the computer graphics error coinciding in this manner? The event of the fraud would be that the numbers are predefined, hard-coded already in the computer before the extraction even began, and the actual physical balls are somehow being sucked out in the desired (rigged) order.

Comment: Yes, I can see how 1 could be confused with a 7, a simple mistake.  With 4 balls drawn, 35 balls remaining, the likelihood of a the number "21" being drawn was 1 out 35 or about 2.9% chance.  Unlikely but not completely rare.  The probability of fraud in this case goes far beyond the math here.  How big was the pot, who won, how corruptible are the lottery's officials?

Comment: The 1/35 chance is not completely rare. It is a normal, regular every day probability. That's not the whole story. The whole story is when you combine that 1/35 probability with the probability of this kind of glitch actually happening (which is never in my life, and probably never in any of the 10 million serbians' lives either).

Comment: There was no jackpot winner, which, under premise that it was rigged, fits perfectly. But, fact is fact, there was no jackpot winner of the so called "sedmica" (the famous "seven").

Comment: It looks likely to be simple, but unfortunate coincidence, & something for which probability calculations aren't going to be really possible without a bunch of untenable assumptions. With thousands of lotteries, each going for many years, drama will occur now & then.